# Make Tkinter Entry widget readonly but selectable

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

Is there any way to make the Tkinter Entry widget so that text can be highlighted and copied, but not changed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the [state option](https://tkdocs.com/shipman/entry.html) "disabled" (all lowercase):

> Use this option to disable the Entry widget so that the user can't
> type anything into it. Use state=tk.DISABLED to disable the widget,
> state=tk.NORMAL to allow user input again. Your program can also find
> out whether the cursor is currently over the widget by interrogating
> this option; it will have the value tk.ACTIVE when the mouse is over
> it. You can also set this option to 'disabled', which is like the
> tk.DISABLED state, but the contents of the widget can still be
> selected or copied.

---

Old answer from 2010...

Use the [state](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm) option `"readonly"`:

> state=
> The entry state: NORMAL, DISABLED, or “readonly” (same as DISABLED, but
> contents can still be selected and
> copied). Default is NORMAL. Note that
> if you set this to DISABLED or
> “readonly”, calls to insert and delete
> are ignored. (state/State)

Comment: The link is no longer valid, and it seems that the "readonly" option has been removed. Under Python 3.9, I am getting the error "bad state "readonly": must be disabled or normal".

Comment: @ChristophThiede, see new answer 13 years later.  Dang, I'm old.

Comment: Oh, that's very helpful, thank you! I would not have believed that `tk.DISABLED` and `disabled` would have a different behavior before trying it out. That's really not a nice design. Thanks!

**Edit:** However, keyboard event handling seems to be limited in this mode. Ctrl + C for copy only works at the first time.

Comment: EDIT 2: "Copy works only once" seems to be a general problem, independently of `disabled`. This might be by the design of Tkinter ... sorry for the confusion!

Comment: On Ubuntu 23.04 with Python 3.11.4 'disabled' behaves just like tk.DISABLED, as far as I can tell, you won't be able to select the content.