# How can I make a read only tkinter.Entry widget?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

This is a sample of the code:

```
entry=Entry(root)
entry.insert(0, "This is a read-only widget")
entry.pack()
```

How to make this entry uneditable?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [make-tkinter-entry-widget-readonly-but-selectable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680301)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `state option` of the `Entry` to `disabled`:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

entry = tk.Entry(root) 
entry.insert(0, "This is a read-only widget")
entry.config(state='disabled')
entry.pack()

root.mainloop()
```